# Unrefinement casting in flow, with nested types in objects (and arrays of said objects)

Tags: javascript, flowtype

Well consider the following snippet, where I have two object types. With the second type being a more refined version of the first type:

```
/* @flow */

type A = {|
  value: string | number,
|}

type B = {|
  value: number,
|}

const b:B = { value: 2 };
const a:A = { value: 2 }; //works.

const z:A = b; //fails, but for javascript it is exactly the same as line above
```

This fails on the last line, since flow tells me that "number" is incompatile with "string". However the type is "union" not intersection, so it should work? (Just to use the type again I'd have to refine it again).

In my real code I'd actually have arrays of said objects, and objects contain a lot more data, so manually copying the object isn't the way to go.

---

I realize this is an abstract overview, but in the end I wish to have a function that takes a "refined A" and returns back "A", ie a more real example:

```
type A = {|
  value: string | number,
  value2: string,
|}

function foo(input: $ReadOnlyArray<{| ...$Exact<A>, value: number|}>): Array<A> {
  return input.filter(v => v.value === 2);
}
```

Is there a better way to say "this function takes a refined version of type X".

Answer (score 1):

The last paragraph in the [Depth Subtyping](https://flow.org/en/docs/lang/depth-subtyping/) page of the docs sort of explains what's happening here (the docs admittedly kinda suck).

> By default, object properties are invariant, which allow both reads and writes, but are more restrictive in the values they accept.

Right now the `value` property on `A` is invariant by default. This means that it *only* accepts its given type, very specifically. You can't assign it something that is `number` or `string`, you can only assign it something that is `number | string`. Anything that has a given type that is more or less explicit than `number | string` won't be accepted:

```
type Ambiguous = {|
  value: string | number,
|};

type Specific = {|
  value: number,
|};

const myAmbiguous: Ambiguous = ({ value: 1 }: Specific); // error!
```

One thing we can do about this is mark the property as covariant, as mentioned earlier in the same paragraph:

> The plus sign indicates that the [...] property is “covariant.” Using a covariant property allows us to use objects which have subtype-compatible values for that property.

This should allow us to assign a more specific type (in this case `number`) to our property:

```
type Ambiguous = {|
  +value: string | number,
|};

type Specific = {|
  value: number,
|};

const myAmbiguous: Ambiguous = ({ value: 1 }: Specific); // all good
```

Note, however, that `value` is now read-only:

```
myAmbiguous.value = 3; // error!
         // ^ Cannot assign `3` to `myAmbiguous.value` 
         //   because property `value` is not writable.
```

I would recommend reading through the rest of that page on Depth Subtyping and also the page on [Type Variance](https://flow.org/en/docs/lang/variance/).

Comment: This would work, as (obviously) after typecasting I consider the value already read-only (it's unsafe otherwise). - However at other places the more generic class `Ambiguous` is created directly, at those place I want to be able to modify. - This would require me to create two versions of all types: with and without covariant properties; if I could do this without a lot of typing that would be neat.

Answer (score 0):

Those are 2 different types and flow doesn’t allow the assignment.

Your 2 lines aren’t the same
- the first one creates an object of type A and assigns it
- the second wants to assign an object of type B to a variable of type A

Comment: Hey, I updated the question to prevent XY-problem, as I think this answer isn't applicable to my situation. Thanks for the reply though.